# Are moderators eligible to delete answers without references?

Tags: discussion

Like [this one](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4856).

This answer (per my opinion) is short, poorly-formatted and contains no references. But it does provide two or three translation-suggestions for the phrase in the question. So it looks like a clear attempt to answer.

I kindly ask all three moderators (and possibly other site users) to express their opinions.

Comment: Your question title and body are inconsistent. Are you asking about (1) the Mods' privileges, (2) our policy regarding half-baked posts, or (3) arguing about another Mod's decision about this particular post?

Comment: @bytebuster, I am asking about rights (and probably responsibilities) of mods in case of posts that they consider half-baked. As an example, I provide specific post and specific mod's reaction. I.e. the general question is then extended by the specific example (general question: "what should and must mods do for such posts?"; then I provide specific example; the question is not about specific example, but providing specific example may help to understand what I'm talking about and an answerer might make some comments about specific example too if he wishes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderator can delete posts that do not conform the rules. The post was published for 2.5 days before it was deleted with a note that it does not conform to the rules. The poster has enough reputation points to leave comments under any post.

Maybe the warning could be doubled using Ukrainian language. Personally I would rather convert the answer to the comment instead of deleting. But I'm totally on moderator's side in this case.

---

Модератор може вилучати пости які не відповідають правилам. Пост провисів 2,5 дня із приміткою що він не відповідає правилам. Користувач має достатній рейтинг щоб залишати коментарі.

Можливо краще було б продублювати попередження українською. Я б особисто перетворив цей пост на коментар. Але в цілому підтримую модератора.

Comment: Зрозуміло. Я, очевидно, з цим незгоден, бо вважаю, що модератори мають «відсвічувати» якнайменше, не заважаючи користувачам творити контент і не псуючи настрій новачкам (якщо спільноті щось не подобається, вона сама замінусує). Але 2 проти 1 — тож хай буде по-вашому. Оскільки свою думку і думку P.Vovk я знаю, то фактично Ваша відповідь є вирішальною, тому я приймаю її (P.S.: мінус ставив не я, але й плюс я ставити теж не буду, бо суб'єктивно незгоден).